# processing canvas tag not included in angular using ng-include or ng-view

Tags: angularjs, processing, angularjs-ng-include

I want to include my processing sketch to angular. My sketch is added to a template file and trying to include the template html file in angular using ng-include or ng-view. I see that the template html get included but missing canvas tag.

I have created a sample plunker... Please help...

[sample is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ZaLzswnnVcf71bwrrgp?p=preview)

```
<canvas data-processing-sources="rect.pde"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can someone please help on this request?